# Animate TextView to increase integer and stop at some point?

Tags: android

I have a TextView showing integer value. Integer value is transferred from previous activity, and I want to add nice animation. I want to if for example int value is 73, I want textView to increase shown number by 1 until 73, so it would be 1-2-3-4-5...etc etc.
How can I do this?

Comment: are you aware of this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: you want animation why?? i mean you can simply use for loop and set the value in textview..and use thread or timer to upadte the text view on particular interval of time

Comment: I don't see how could I achieve what I want with NumberPicker. My TextView is more like a score.

Comment: @MeenalSharma Well it would look like its animated but it doesn't have to be. Your idea looks like a solution.

Comment: try this https://github.com/uguratar/countingtextview

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is a simple function to animate the text of a textView according to an initial and final value

```
public void animateTextView(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView textview) {
        DecelerateInterpolator decelerateInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator(0.8f);
        int start = Math.min(initialValue, finalValue);
        int end = Math.max(initialValue, finalValue);
        int difference = Math.abs(finalValue - initialValue);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        for (int count = start; count <= end; count++) {
            int time = Math.round(decelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation((((float) count) / difference)) * 100) * count;
            final int finalCount = ((initialValue > finalValue) ? initialValue - count : count);
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textview.setText(String.valueOf(finalCount));
                }
            }, time);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this guy deserves a cookie

Comment: Isn't it better to use Animator instead of handle it directly?

Answer (score 102):

The best solution in my opinion is to use this method :

```
public void animateTextView(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView  textview) {

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            textview.setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());

        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();

}
```

Comment: Best function! Work perfectly!

Comment: wonderful ! Just a remark, though : no need to cast `initialValue` and `finalValue` to **int** since `ValueAnimator.ofInt` expects **integers** ;-)

Comment: Oops! Works like  a charm. the above solution by Pedro Oliveira do not work with max to min number animation.... This solution is awesome... the animation is smooth...better performance.

Answer (score 3):

I think this project in github is what you want: https://github.com/sd6352051/RiseNumber

The RiseNumberTextView extends TextView and use the ValueAnimator to implement the rising number effect.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Kotlin code for incrementing from initial value to final value over a duration of time. Here I have used duration of 5 sec.

```
 fun animateTextView(initialValue: Int, finalValue: Int, textView: TextView) {
        val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue)
        valueAnimator.duration = 5000 // 5 sec
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator -> textView.text = valueAnimator.animatedValue.toString() }
        valueAnimator.start()
    }
```

use this code in Utilities and call the method accordingly with required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

try this code..showing increment value with animation

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    private TextView textView;
    AlphaAnimation fadeIn, fadeOut;

    private static int count = 0, finalValue = 20;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);

        fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
        fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
        fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
        fadeOut.setFillAfter(true);

        fadeIn.setAnimationListener(this);
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(this);
        textView.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        textView.startAnimation(fadeOut);

    }   

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("mini", "Count:" + count);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textView.setText("" + count);
            }
        });

        if (count == finalValue) {
            textView.setText("" + finalValue);
        } else {
            ++count;
            textView.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            textView.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```