# How to implement increasing number animation from 0 to 600 in 5 secs on TextVIew on android

Tags: android, animation, textview

I plan to implement integer number increase on textView from 0 to some value with animation within certain seconds.
e.g show animation which increase number from 0 to 600 on textview for 5 seconds duration.

How can I implement this?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You could use the [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) for that:

```
private void startCountAnimation() {
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 600);
    animator.setDuration(5000);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            textView.setText(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at [this simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31476531/4729523):

```
public void animateTextView(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView  textview) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
           textview.setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();

}
```

Comment: Yes friend.... this is easy and perfect solution ... great. I managed to implement it for some counting points depending on variables in a little game. Thanks very much for sharing this method.

Answer (score 7):

I propose answer here for Kotlin developers :

```
 fun startAnimation(textView: TextView) {
    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 600) 
    animator.duration = 5000 // 5 seconds
    animator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
        textView.text = animation.animatedValue.toString()
    }
    animator.start()
}
```

Flexible extension in Kotlin:

```
fun TextView.animateNumberChange(startingNumber: Int, endingNumber: Int, duration: Long = 500L) {
    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startingNumber, endingNumber)
    animator.duration = duration
    animator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
        this.text = animation.animatedValue.toString()
    }
    animator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    animator.start()
}

// usage:
myTextView.animateNumberChange(1, 10)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a ValueAnimator

```
TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textview1);

ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 600);
valueAnimator.setDuration(5000);
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
       textview.setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());
   }
});
valueAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here : 
[Animate TextView to increase integer and stop at some point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502819/animate-textview-to-increase-integer-and-stop-at-some-point)

and a nice lib here : https://github.com/sd6352051/RiseNumber