# Raising double Number animation Android

Tags: android, animation

I have to do Raising number animation. The double number that I pass dynamically should raise from 0.0 to that particular number within 1 sec.

I tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443767/how-to-implement-increasing-number-animation-from-0-to-600-in-5-secs-on-textview). It works perfectly fine. But the problem is I could do only integer number animation. I want the double number. Can someone help me out do that?

Thanks

Comment: ValueAnimator has setFloatValues(float... values) method.  Can you try that ?

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. It worked