# Spin animation on textview update

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview, android-animation

I want to know how do I achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oKI5.jpg). So, if the updated digit is smaller the the spin is from up to down and if its bigger then its vice-versa. The digits which remain same in update don't animate.

I wish to implement it in observe block of a livedata so that as soon as data changes in room the textview animates to reflect that change

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement increasing number animation from 0 to 600 in 5 secs on TextVIew on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443767/how-to-implement-increasing-number-animation-from-0-to-600-in-5-secs-on-textview)

Comment: @kelvin No, I don't want anything related to intervals. I just want a plain simple animation

Comment: https://github.com/everalbum/roliedex you can use something like this

Comment: @UsamaAltaf it might serve the purpose. I'll try it