# How to make a number animation slide up and change it's value like in this gif? Android

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, numbers, slide

I want to implement something exactly like the animation in this gif. Both of the views. Animated numbers.
How can I achieve that? I just couldn't find an answer, Tbh I don't even know what to look for. Appreciate any help in this direction!

[image: example]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443767/how-to-implement-increasing-number-animation-from-0-to-600-in-5-secs-on-textview  does this help?

Comment: @DanBaruch I also found that question but it does not help, at least I have no clue how to improve from that solution

Comment: Then you should've posted what you searched for, what you have tried, what have failed and give more explanation

Comment: https://github.com/kavitamp/Rolling-TextView-Animation May be it will helps.

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb that one doesn't help

Comment: After a lot of research I've found a hint using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher). I will update the thread after I try to implement my last solution reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution based on [TextSwitcher](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-textswitcher-with-animation-in-android-using-java/). Using custom animations, this UI widget handles the TextViews and creates the desired effect.

In the end, I created a highly customisable new library to spare other developers of wasting time for this explicit need. [Plus Minus Quantity CardView Library](https://github.com/radustavila/Plus-Minus-Quantity-Card-Android-Library)

Here is an example of usage:

[image: Quantity CardView]