# Android: Animating a TextView to Increase its Value (float) over Time in Android

Tags: android

I have a TextView in Android which will display float value. I want to show an animation in which its value increases from 0 to the given float value in a given time. I need the digits after the decimal place to be animated as well.

Also, I tried the following solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502819/animate-textview-to-increase-integer-and-stop-at-some-point) by Pedro Oliveira but it works only for int values. I am more concerned about animating float values.

```
public void animateTextView(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView textview) {
    DecelerateInterpolator decelerateInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator(0.8f);
    int start = Math.min(initialValue, finalValue);
    int end = Math.max(initialValue, finalValue);
    int difference = Math.abs(finalValue - initialValue);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    for (int count = start; count <= end; count++) {
        int time = Math.round(decelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation((((float) count) / difference)) * 100) * count;
        final int finalCount = ((initialValue > finalValue) ? initialValue - count : count);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textview.setText(finalCount + "");
            }
        }, time);
    }
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? What do you have trouble with? The timer? The string formatting? To avoid getting this many down votes, I recommend to provide more information in the future. Right now, the question looks like: _"I've got this problem and didn't try anything, just tell me the solution."_

Comment: the easiest way is to use an `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I realise that I haven't provided much information. But after twiddling around with a solution given in another question, I found the answer which I'm posting below.

Comment: *please stop downvoting.* ---> Why ? Your question is still bad, you have made no effort for others, so why should others make efforts for you ? Food for thoughts.

Comment: @2Dee Haven't I posted the answer already? If that doesn't count as an effort, I don't know what does.

Comment: Yes, you *obviously* don't know, I gathered that much. Luckily, there's a very well done help section that addresses the subject of how to ask a good question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look.

Comment: @2Dee There. Does it seem OK now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502819/animate-textview-to-increase-integer-and-stop-at-some-point) question. AhmedZah's answer worked perfectly for me, I just changed the code slightly.

```
 public void animateTextView(float initialValue, float finalValue, final TextView  textview) {

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            textview.setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());

        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();

}
```

I doubt that this question will get any more views owing to the number of downvotes, but I hope this will help someone in desperate need of an answer :).