# Android Studio Java: how do I force a redraw / display of the textbox during the loop?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have the following code, which I was hoping would count up to 3 million on the screen.

It compiles and runs, displaying 3,000,000 at the end on the emulator. My question is how do I force a redraw / display of the textbox during the loop please?

```
/** Called when the activity has become visible. */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(msg, "The onResume() event");
        TextView textbox1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        for(double l=0; l<=3000000; l++){
            textbox1.setText("" + l);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain. What you need to do?

Comment: Describe the output you're expecting

Comment: I would like to see the value visibly count upwards in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

The view is only disabled *after* `onResume` has finished running.

You may want to set the text in the textview, update some state in the activity (like an int field), and register some code to run after a while and increment. Look at using [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.htm), [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), or other options to defer code.

Here's a quick-and-dirty example with `Handler`.

```
final long DELAY_MILLIS = 50;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
int num = 0;
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    if (num >= 3000000) return;
    textbox1.setText("" + num);
    num++;
    // re-register ourself to run in DELAY_MILLIS;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, DELAY_MILLIS);
  }
};

TextView textbox1;

protected void onResume() {
  // more efficient to look this up once
  this.textbox1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
  runnable.run(); // will register itself to re-run
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31476531/4035036) answer the best way to show an incremental value in a `TextView` is to use `ValueAnimator`

```
public void animateTextView(int initialValue, int finalValue, final TextView  textview) {

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            textview.setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```