# Android studio - animating adding to 10 using textview?

Tags: android-studio, animation, textview

Can I animate an increase in a score variable using a textview over 1 second?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502819/animate-textview-to-increase-integer-and-stop-at-some-point), there are various approaches that works differently for different cases.

You could try:

```
//You can animate from a specified starting point till the final score
val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialScore, finalScore)

//Here you set the duration of the animation in milliseconds
valueAnimator.duration = 1000 


valueAnimator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator -> 
    //The textview gets updates as the value animator's value updates
    textView.text = valueAnimator.animatedValue.toString() 

}

//Here you just start the animation
valueAnimator.start()
```

This could also be repurposed into it's own method ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which works well is to use new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() ... such as:

```
private void wonBlockIncreaseScore() {
        int oldScore = score;
        score = score + 50;
        int timeOverWhichAnimationShouldRun = 1000; //ms
        int equalGap = (timeOverWhichAnimationShouldRun / (score-oldScore));
        //equal gap...
        for (int i = oldScore; i < score; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scoreTextView.setText(String.valueOf(finalI+1));
                }
            }, (equalGap * i));
        }
```