# Animate TextView to increase double value and stop at some point?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, mvvm

I have a TextView showing double value. Double value is transferred from API response, and I want to add animation. I want to if, for example, the double value is 2.3, I want text View to increase shown number by 0.0 until 2.3, so it would be 0.1-0.2-0.3... etc. How can I do this? I have seen examples with Value Animator but they only work with integers. Ps. my code it's in Kotlin.

Comment: Check out this library. It’s a very specific animation, but might work for you. https://github.com/robinhood/ticker

Comment: Do you know any another library that numbers don't slide?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void animateTextView(float initialValue, float finalValue, final TextView  textview) {

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            textview.setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());

        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();

}
```

Comment: This one works, but it shows a lot of numbers, do you know how to show only two numbers after .

Comment: @flutra you can follow this for answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502819/animate-textview-to-increase-integer-and-stop-at-some-point?rq=1. But if my answer also helped you please vote for it.

Comment: Your answer helped me, but I don't have enough reputation to vote since I am new member in Stack

Comment: @flutra Can you accept this as an answer? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the first answer was helpful. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Can you click on the tick to make it green below the number it's grey right now.

Comment: To limit it to two digits after the decimal, replace `valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString()` with `String.format("%.2f", valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue())`.